# Need to identify which HTML button was clicked on Google Signin

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I have been wanting to implement the new Google SignIn, but found an issue: there's no way to identify the HTML button that was clicked with the Google SignIn API. Why do I need that?

Because I have 2 features in my website: users can login into the website and comment in blog posts, but also subscribe to the website. **I need a way to identify which button was clicked by the user to call the right javascript function.**

Thanks in advance,
Guilherme.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an id at each button and depending which button was clicked send the id of that button.

Comment: I say if you have 2 buttons, the button one has the id 1 and the second has the id 2. You can validate the function do you wanna execute depend the id.
I recomended use a switch to control the default value

Answer (score 0):

You can also now use the [`click_listener`](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#click_listener) property to specify a function to be called specifically when the Sign in with Google button is clicked.

The property is also available in the [HTML reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference#click_listener)